# Laravel Model Controller Dependency injection

Tags: laravel, oop, laravel-5, dependency-injection

I have the following problem. I hope my approach is not completely wrong, feel free to advice.

I have a Model class `Chat.php`

```php
protected $skip;
protected $take;
protected $agreements;
protected $chat;


public function getSkip()
{
    return $this->skip;
}

public function setSkip($skip)
{
    $this->skip = $skip;
}

public function getTake()
{
    return $this->take;
}

public function setTake($take)
{
    $this->take = $take;
}

public function __construct(array $attributes = array())
{
    parent::__construct($attributes);

    $this->setTake(8);
    $this->setSkip(8);
}
```

I set properties `skip` and `take` here.

Then, I have the `DashboardController`

```php
class DashboardController extends Controller
{

private $chat;

/**
 * DashboardController constructor.
 * @param $chat
 */
public function __construct(Chat $chat)
{
    $this->chat = $chat;
}


/**
 * Display a listing of the authenticated resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{


    $chats = Chat::orderBy('created_at','desc')->skip($this->chat->getSkip())->take($this->chat->getTake())->get();


    $agreements = AgrType::orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(10)->get();


    return view('sections.dashboard', compact('chats','agreements'));
}

public function loadMore()
{

    $this->chat->setSkip($this->chat->getSkip() - 1 );

    $this->chat->setTake($this->chat->getTake() - 1);



    return redirect('/dashboard');

}
```

**My approach is as follows:**

After a user clicks on button, route `/loadmore` get him to this controller and triggers `loadMore` function.

`LoadMore` function then gets values through accessors and sets values with mutator.

Index method then simply reads this values.

So the meaning is: I show chat window (rather maybe comments window cause this si not really a chat), index method is called.

Index method reads the values and displays comments according to query. -> this one is OK

**Now, what does NOT work:**

When I click button, loadMore function gets called, sets the values which index method then reads and reloads according to them.

What did I try: I tried loadMore method to display its own values (changed) and return them, but then I have a new route for reloaded chat and it is not what I want.

What do I miss? Is my approach OK? (I know javascript is maybe better for this, but I want a Laravel way, get and post.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not obvious from your code how it is expected to work. I believe you should find a simpler way to implement your idea so other developers could easily understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller functions get executed within in completely separate requests.

All `return redirect('/dashboard');` does in `loadMore()` send your browser to the dashboard route. Your browser then makes a new request to `index()` on which your controller gets instantiated again, its `__construct()` function run again and a new empty `Chat` model gets instantiated.

I recommend you put the take and skip parameters into your url like this:

`$router->get('/dashboard/{skip}/{take}', 'DashboardController@index');`

And change your `index()` function to this:

`public function index($skip, $take)`

That way it will work, however the even better way of doing it would be to use Laravel's `paginate()` function: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination

```
public function index()
{
    $chats = Chat::orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate();

    $agreements = AgrType::orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(10)->get();

    return view('sections.dashboard', compact('chats','agreements'));
}
```

Comment: I don't think I understart the paginate function completely, could you edit your answer to help me paginate results? Thanks in advance

Comment: No problem, this should do it.

Comment: yes pagination works, thank you, not exactly what I wanted but I get the trick.